# Formatting #N/A in OpenOffice Calc/Excel

Tags: excel, openoffice-calc

Is there a way to hide or at least change the color of cells whose results are #N/A without modifying the cell formula? Or any type of error for that matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel, you can change the color of the cell based on whether there is an error in the cell or not.

1. Select cells which you want the new color condition to apply to.
2. Choose Format|Conditional Formatting
3. From the first dropdown, choose Formula Is
4. For the formula, enter a formula that refers to the active cell in the selection:
   =ISERROR(C2)
   or, to hide only #N/A errors: =ISNA(C2)
5. Click the Format button.
6. Select the color you want. You can match the cell background or whatever you like.
7. Click OK twice.

Comment: All the zeros turned white, but the #N/As are still there.